# SQL Table Restriction

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, check-constraint

How can I  specify, 5 distinct values for a varchar column in Oracle Application Express?

I need a column called tipo_conta (varchar) that only accepts 'Conta a ordem', 'Multibanco', 'Rendimento', 'Jovem', 'Rendimento-Habitacao' as possible values.

I tried this but I get this error - ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis.

What am I doing wrong?

```
CREATE TABLE contas 
(
id_conta NUMBER(6),
tipo_conta VARCHAR2(20),
CONSTRAINT id_conta PRIMARY KEY(id_conta),
CONSTRAINT tipo_conta UNIQUE (tipo_conta)
CONSTRAINT chk_tipo_conta CHECK (Frequency IN ('Conta a ordem', 'Multibanco', 'Rendimento', 'Jovem', 'Rendimento-Habitacao'))
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it looks like you are missing a comma in your CONSTRAINT CLAUSES over here:

`CONSTRAINT tipo_conta UNIQUE (tipo_conta)`

should instead be:

`CONSTRAINT tipo_conta UNIQUE (tipo_conta),`

---

Also your `CHECK` does not reference the column properly:

Instead of `CONSTRAINT chk_tipo_conta CHECK (Frequency IN ...`

try `CONSTRAINT chk_tipo_conta CHECK (tipo_conta IN ...`

Comment: You are right. I did that but now I have this error - ORA-00904: "FREQUENCY": invalid identifier

Comment: @Dany4k There's a problem with the `CHECK` clause, see the updated answer.

Comment: Oracle does not have enums

Comment: Your quote is from the **MySQL** manual, not from the Oracle database.

Comment: I forgot they moved all that to thw oracle site. Not the first time I've tripped up on that either